# PHP which is the best practice array(...) or [...]

Tags: php, arrays

Since newer version of PHP allow to use box braces for array and found many code now using it for arrays, I just wonder to know if either make any real difference in terms of performance and other aspect or it is just a visual difference.

So which one is better or best practice to use? I am just about to start writing new plugin so before it I would like to know more on it.

Comment: If your plug-in is expected to run on earlier versions of PHP, then you need to use the `array()` syntax; but it has absolutely no difference internally

Comment: if you want maximum compatibility then stick with `array()` notation otherwise use latest `[]` implementation

Comment: Cool.. I got it now.. :))

Comment: To be honest, since PHP 5.3 is now at end-of-life, you shouldn't really be considering using it or supporting it anyway, so stick with the `[]` syntax; it's a lot easier to work with. You need to know about the `array()` syntax as well as a lot of third party code still uses it so you'll need to be able to read that code, but there's no reason for you to use the longer syntax for yourself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`[]` notation requires a minimum PHP version of 5.4. That's the only significant difference. If you do not plan on supporting versions of PHP before 5.4, use the shorthand notation. There's absolutely no performance impact or anything else, it's literally **just shorter**.

Comment: Oh I see.. so if I want to support only new version than can use `[...]`.. Thanks for clearing my confusion..

Comment: Yes indeed. And since there are many more useful additions in 5.4+ and old version are already deprecated, the choice should be pretty simple. You'd need a very concrete reason to be supporting anything older.

Answer (score 4):

Parenthesis `()` works in all versions of PHP but square brackets `[]` are in PHP versions 5.4+.

There is no difference in speed or the way PHP handles the two.

[W3Schools link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array.asp)

Comment: Yes I did! Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: "4+ for `()`"...?! I'd think that syntax goes back much further than PHP 4.

Comment: @deceze I would have thought so too but the W3Schools page suggests that it's only accepted in 4+... Check the "Technical Details" subsection. I don't doubt the validity of the source but it would be interesting to know the notation before PHP4...

Comment: Don't take W3S as authority on anything. A quick Google search suggests that syntax existed in PHP 3 at the very least: http://vsbabu.org/tutorials/php/index-2.html

Answer (score 2):

As @deceze and @Ben said shorthand syntax works in 5.4 and above. I can only add that shorthand syntax is better to be read and also easier to understand by people who don't write in PHP. For example (Ruby, Python, Javascript) has similar syntax for arrays.

`[]` are used for better readablity

[Here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortsyntaxforarrays) you will find pros/cons of this solution

Answer (score 0):

from what php docs tell us there is no differences between both just someone think creating arrays with [] will me more readable when writing multidimensional arrays by me opinion will be same mess even bigger